# Edit just for earning reputation?

Tags: discussion, editing

I don't know I am wrong or right I just need to share my thoughts. 
Today I found that one user have continuously made an edit in questions and edits are also approved. Edits are very minor just for earning reputations, there is no meaning of such  edits. 
Below is some links that you may check

[Magento 2 - Free Shipping / Drop Off (shipping) charge based on specific zip codes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216948/magento-2-free-shipping-drop-off-shipping-charge-based-on-specific-zip-cod)

[Magmi not saving checked options on mac](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304/magmi-not-saving-checked-options-on-mac)

[What is a good method to handle suspected fraudulent transactions with Authorize.net?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309/what-is-a-good-method-to-handle-suspected-fraudulent-transactions-with-authorize)

[What is 'best practice' when setting anchor on multi-level categories?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-is-best-practice-when-setting-anchor-on-multi-level-categories)

[Conflicts in where clause with ambiguous column names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262/conflicts-in-where-clause-with-ambiguous-column-names)

[Change the template inheritance hierarchy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290/change-the-template-inheritance-hierarchy)

[Multiple local.xml layout files in a package](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217/multiple-local-xml-layout-files-in-a-package)

[Onepage checkout, or not Onepage checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89/onepage-checkout-or-not-onepage-checkout)

some of them are 5 year old question, and in most of this edits there is no meaning or usefulness.
should we really allow such things in the community ?

Should we really allow such edits ?

Please correct me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd even consider these edits harmful. They are using quotes to highlight random paragraphs which are not remotely quotes.

**What to do in such a case?** Flag one of the answers/questions for moderator attention and mention that this particular user is vandalizing in their edits. You don't need to include a whole list of edits, the moderators can see the edit history for any user.

**I rolled back the edits.** Please be more careful when reviewing, if you read this:

> **Rama Chandran M** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve
>   **Prince Patel** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve
>
> **saravanavelu** reviewed this 3 hours ago: Approve
>   **Rama Chandran M** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve
>
> **saravanavelu** reviewed this 3 hours ago: Approve
>   **Rama Chandran M** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve
>
> **Prince Patel** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>   **Murtuza Zabuawala** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>
> **Qaisar Satti** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>   **Prince Patel** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>
> **Rama Chandran M** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>   **Qaisar Satti** reviewed this 2 hours ago: Approve
>
> **Rama Chandran M** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve
>   **Jai** reviewed this 4 hours ago: Approve

#### Friendly formatting reminder

`>` for **quotes**, ``` `` ``` for **code**, `*`/`**` for **highlighting**

Comment: I approve of what Fabian said. Just for the record, the user has been notified to stop this practice.

Comment: Any words about this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/121464 ... *The issue was missing media folder.* Isnt it a possible answer? @Marius

Comment: @sv3n I didn't delete that. Also don't mix issues.

Comment: Just mentioned you, to check this ;) Didnt want to open a new question and thought it fits to this.

Comment: @sv3n,can u please tell me why you are  thought that that this is  an  answer. My point of view, i not thought that one single line is give  that answer. user should be more details. marius &Fabian what your thought about this?

Comment: It's usually missing write permission, but a missing directory may cause it as well, so the answer is valid. They don't explain why, but probably just don't know. Still it can be helpful, although it is not a very good answer. Let the votes decide I'd say, nothing to delete.

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchmengler for advise.I have undo the delete

Comment: @AmitBera as said above, the 2nd sentence is answer to me. Not a good on, but it's an answer. :)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Thanks for your advice i will be more careful next time.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Thanks for the advice. Take care next time.

Comment: This is becoming a serious issue in my assessment. You'll find users such as Teja bhagavan Kollepara continually spamming edits on out of date answers/questions causing them to resurface. Users engaging in these activities should just have their accounts deleted.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Next time I will look carefully the edit and low-quality post.

Comment: QaisarSatti, PrincePatel, RamaChandranM: Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: @Eirik Teja isnt a good example (imho), I know he does a lot of minor edits (e.g. replace "magneto" with "magento") ... I agree with this and it takes no time to review, since he already was above 2k REP and can edit w/o reviews. Sometimes it's bit anoying to have some old quesetions bumped, but it doest hurt.

Comment: @sv3n can't we do something to avoid such ting?

Comment: @Magento2Learner avoid which kind of things? The edits you have posted in your question are useless. They should be reported (here) so a moderator can contact the person to stop this. Edits that improve grammer/spelling (like Teja does) or improve tags are useful (imho), even if they bring up old or closed questions.